# OpenGL rotate camera around a point

Tags: opengl, camera, rotation

I have seen a lot of answers on this theme, but when I try to make it work.. it doesn't.

```
curtarget = cameraPos + cameraFront;
cameraPos = cameraPos - curtarget;
GLfloat xoffset = 45.0f;

GLfloat cosa = cos(glm::radians(xoffset));
GLfloat sina = sin(glm::radians(xoffset));
newP.x = cameraPos.x*cosa - cameraPos.z*sina;//frontradius*cos(glm::radians(xoffset));
newP.z = cameraPos.x*sina + cameraPos.z*cosa;//frontradius*sin(glm::radians(xoffset));
newP.y = cameraPos.y;

cameraFront.x = cameraFront.x*cosa - cameraFront.z*sina;
cameraFront.z = cameraFront.x*sina + cameraFront.z*cosa;
cameraFront.y = cameraFront.y;

cameraPos = curtarget + newP;
lastalpha += xoffset;

view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraFront + cameraPos, cameraUp);
```

So the target remains the same. Initially, I have front (0, 0, -1), cameraPos (0, 0, 3), so target (0, 0, 2). Then I subtract target point (first two lines are only for rotating (0,0,1) vector, not (0, 0, -1)) and rotate around center, then add it again. At the same time I rotate front point in order to leave target constant. However, I get strange numbers.

Comment: "strange numbers" isn't very descriptive of a problem.

Comment: @Vallentin, front vector and translated to origin vector are not the same concerning absolute values ( after rotating. So all other results also.